# How to correctly index fields within a struct by index

Tags: c#, unsafe

I have the following code.

```
public class BoxCorners
{
    public Vector3 V000;
    public Vector3 V001;
    public Vector3 V010;
    public Vector3 V011;

    public Vector3 V100;
    public Vector3 V101;
    public Vector3 V110;
    public Vector3 V111;

    public Vector3 Index(int i)
    {
        if (i > 7)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException($"{i}");
        }
        unsafe
        {
            fixed (Vector3 * v = &V000)
            {
                return v[i];
            }
        }

    }
}
```

where `Vector3` is a struct as well with three doubles.

```
public struct Vector3 {
   double X;double Y; double Z;
}
```

Is the above a robust way to index the fields by number? Or do I have to specify some packing attributes to ensure that it works.

The use case is that sometimes I need to index by name and sometimes by number. I am happy to work at the metal with unsafe code if it solves some performance problems. This code is used in a very tight loop running millions of times. Physics engine type stuff so fast is better than pretty.